# How to run PATCHMATCH source code for inpainting

Tags: image, algorithm, matlab, image-processing, mingw

Please, help me run source patchmatch.
main page of the paper with source code: http://gfx.cs.princeton.edu/pubs/Barnes_2009_PAR/index.php

and the link of source code:

http://www.cs.princeton.edu/gfx/pubs/Barnes_2009_PAR/patchmatch-2.1.zip

My problem is that I followed the instruction in the readme.txt file and ran build_windows.bat in terminal of Windows 10,but got an error which says:
`Unknown MEX argument '-inline'.`
`Unknown MEX argument '-inline'.`
I removed -inline and execute the bat file in terminal and fortunately it worked and got this message:

````
Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C++)'.
In file included from C:/MinGW/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/backward/hash_set:60:0,
                 from C:\patchmatch-2.1\patchmatch-2.1\knn.cpp:11:
C:/MinGW/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/backward/backward_warning.h:32:2: warning: #warning This file includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header which may be removed without further notice at a future date. Please use a non-deprecated interface with equivalent functionality instead. For a listing of replacement headers and interfaces, consult the file backward_warning.h. To disable this warning use -Wno-deprecated. [-Wcpp]
 #warning \
  ^
C:\patchmatch-2.1\patchmatch-2.1\knn.cpp:42:17: error: 'stdext' is not a namespace-name
 using namespace stdext;
                 ^
C:\patchmatch-2.1\patchmatch-2.1\knn.cpp:42:23: error: expected namespace-name before ';' token
 using namespace stdext;
                       ^
C:\patchmatch-2.1\patchmatch-2.1\knn.cpp: In function 'void knn_check_n(Params*, BITMAP*, BITMAP*, VECBITMAP<int>*, VECBITMAP<int>*, VECBITMAP<int>*, int)':
C:\patchmatch-2.1\patchmatch-2.1\knn.cpp:4500:7: error: 'hash_set' was not declared in this scope
       hash_set<int> pos;
       ^
C:\patchmatch-2.1\patchmatch-2.1\knn.cpp:4500:7: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from C:\patchmatch-2.1\patchmatch-2.1\knn.cpp:11:0:
C:/MinGW/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/backward/hash_set:84:11: note:   '__gnu_cxx::hash_set'
     class hash_set
           ^
C:\patchmatch-2.1\patchmatch-2.1\knn.cpp:4500:16: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
       hash_set<int> pos;
                ^
C:\patchmatch-2.1\patchmatch-2.1\knn.cpp:4502:33: error: 'pos' was not declared in this scope
         if (check_duplicates && pos.count(p_ann[i])) { fprintf(stderr, "duplicate element at %d,%d: %d,%d (d=%d)\n", x, y, INT_TO_X(p_ann[i]), INT_TO_Y(p_ann[i]), p_annd[i]); exit(1); }
                                 ^
C:\patchmatch-2.1\patchmatch-2.1\knn.cpp:4503:9: error: 'pos' was not declared in this scope
         pos.insert(p_ann[i]);
         ^

Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C++)'.
In file included from C:/MinGW/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/backward/hash_set:60:0,
                 from C:\patchmatch-2.1\patchmatch-2.1\knn.cpp:11:
C:/MinGW/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/backward/backward_warning.h:32:2: warning: #warning This file includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header which may be removed without further notice at a future date. Please use a non-deprecated interface with equivalent functionality instead. For a listing of replacement headers and interfaces, consult the file backward_warning.h. To disable this warning use -Wno-deprecated. [-Wcpp]
 #warning \
  ^
C:\patchmatch-2.1\patchmatch-2.1\knn.cpp:42:17: error: 'stdext' is not a namespace-name
 using namespace stdext;
                 ^
C:\patchmatch-2.1\patchmatch-2.1\knn.cpp:42:23: error: expected namespace-name before ';' token
 using namespace stdext;
                       ^
C:\patchmatch-2.1\patchmatch-2.1\knn.cpp: In function 'void knn_check_n(Params*, BITMAP*, BITMAP*, VECBITMAP<int>*, VECBITMAP<int>*, VECBITMAP<int>*, int)':
C:\patchmatch-2.1\patchmatch-2.1\knn.cpp:4500:7: error: 'hash_set' was not declared in this scope
       hash_set<int> pos;
       ^
C:\patchmatch-2.1\patchmatch-2.1\knn.cpp:4500:7: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from C:\patchmatch-2.1\patchmatch-2.1\knn.cpp:11:0:
C:/MinGW/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/backward/hash_set:84:11: note:   '__gnu_cxx::hash_set'
     class hash_set
           ^
C:\patchmatch-2.1\patchmatch-2.1\knn.cpp:4500:16: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
       hash_set<int> pos;
                ^
C:\patchmatch-2.1\patchmatch-2.1\knn.cpp:4502:33: error: 'pos' was not declared in this scope
         if (check_duplicates && pos.count(p_ann[i])) { fprintf(stderr, "duplicate element at %d,%d: %d,%d (d=%d)\n", x, y, INT_TO_X(p_ann[i]), INT_TO_Y(p_ann[i]), p_annd[i]); exit(1); }
                                 ^
C:\patchmatch-2.1\patchmatch-2.1\knn.cpp:4503:9: error: 'pos' was not declared in this scope
         pos.insert(p_ann[i]);```

I dont understand reason for dont build bat file
````

Comment: Consider that this source code was written in 2009 (by the name), which is 11 years ago. A lot has changed about MATLAB in 11 years.

Comment: Removing `-inline` should be fine. [Here](http://bioinformatics.intec.ugent.be/MotifSuite/INCLUSive_for_users/CPU_64/Matlab_Compiler_Runtime/v79/bin/util/mex/mexHelp.txt) is a copy of an old documentation page for the `mex` command that describes what the option did. It's just one of the many options that have disappeared over the years.

Comment: Also notice the very first warning you get when compiling: "This file includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header which may be removed without further notice at a future date. Please use a non-deprecated interface with equivalent functionality instead." The source code is using antiquated functionality that is no longer supported. Maybe picking an appropriate C++ standard level might help?

Comment: @CrisLuengo ,What versions do you recommend?